# How can I get a Kernel Core Dump

Tags: 10.04, kernel

We're trying to debug a kernel panic/oops on Ubuntu 10.04.  The stacktrace isn't quite enough for us.  How can we configure the system to spit out a core dump and where can we find it after the crash?

There is a lot of information on how to get a user-mode core dump, but very little (or old) information on getting a kernel core dump.

[LKCD](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Linux-Crash-HOWTO.html) exists, but looks as though it hasn't been updated since 2002.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Installing the `linux-crashdump` package will install the kexec tools and set up grub to pass the needed kernel options to have the crashdump kernel available.

This should automatically catch kernel crashes.  For non-crash kernel problems such as an oops you should be able to use the [magic sysrq key's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Magic_commands) `c` command to kexec the crashdump kernel and get a dump.

You may also want to enable apport to have the dump nicely processed into a crash report for submission to Launchpad or for local retracing.  To do that you need to edit `/etc/default/apport`.

Comment: how to run linux-crashdump and get the last crash report of ubuntu 11.10?